# List all the ways a block device is in use

Tags: linux, hard-disk, block-device, removable-storage

I want to be sure that a removable hard drive (USB, but this shouldn't matter) is safe to remove. Let's say this drive is `sdb`.

Obviously I need to make sure that there is no mounted filesystem on that drive. `grep /dev/sdb /proc/mounts` will tell me.

But that's not the whole story. For example, if there is an LVM physical volume on `sdb`, I need to deactivate all volume groups that contain a physical volume located on `sdb` (`lvchange -an my_volume_group/my_logical_volume` then `vgchange -an my_volume_group`). If there is a RAID volume, I may need to deactivate it (`mdadm -S`), or I may want to mark the component as failed (`mdadm -f`).

Is there a way to list all the ways a disk is in use? For my use case, I need to be confident that this list is exhaustive, so that I can unplug the device if the list is empty.

Answer (score 5):

If you are able to open a block device `O_EXCL`, it isn't in use by the kernel (`O_EXCL` takes a device lock in this particular case). lsof (/proc scanning) should find any other users (VMs might have the device open, and often fail to open exclusively).

Answer (score 3):

+1 for Gabriel's answer - `O_EXCL` is exactly the solution I used in this scenario. Here's the Perl function I wrote to check if a device is in use:

```
use Fcntl;
use Errno;

sub device_in_use($)
{
  my $device = shift;
  # open with O_EXCL returns EBUSY if a device is in use
  # http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/open.2.html
  return $!{EBUSY} if (!sysopen my $fh, $device, O_EXCL);
  close $fh;
  return 0;
}
```

Beware though that it doesn't have proper error handling - it expects the device to exist and that you have root permissions.